# How to get survey response as PDF through API in SurveyMonkey?

Tags: api, salesforce, integration, surveymonkey

I have gone through the API documentation of Survey Monkey but i am unable to find any option for retrieving the PDF associated to the response through the API.I need to import it in salesforce. Is there any work around for that?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API to create a PDF of your responses at the moment with SurveyMonkey.

You can [watch the docs](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs) for updates on when that is added. If you're interested, there is a Salesforce integration coming you can [fill the form here](https://www.surveymonkey.com/business/contact-us-salesforce-integration-lp/) if you're interested.